# Entity framework 7 Soft Delete

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

How I can implement soft delete in entity framework 7 in .net core or mvc6?

In entity framework 6 in easy to implement, but I don't know which package install in DNX and implement soft delete in entity framework 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can override SaveChanges function.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var objectStateEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
      .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseEntity && e.State != EntityState.Detached && e.State != EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();
        var currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        foreach (var entry in objectStateEntries)
        {
            var entityBase = entry.Entity as BaseEntity;
            if (entityBase == null) continue;
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    {
                        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                        entityBase.DeletedTime = currentTime;
                        entityBase.IsDeleted = true;
                        break;
                    }
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entityBase.UpdatedTime = currentTime;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entityBase.CreatedTime = currentTime;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My BaseEntity Class:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedTime { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what happens with the navigation properties loaded in the context?